# Is $f$ an absolutely continuous function?

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis

Let 
$$
f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(2^{n}\pi x)}{n\cdot2^{n}}, \,\,\,\,\,\, x\in [-1, 1].
$$
Is $f$ an absolutely continuous function? If yes how can I show it?  If not how about on total variation of $f$?